# Why in Sahih Muslim 1530c (4018) does it say that Rasulullah (SAW) commanded all dogs to be killed?

Tags: hadith, dogs

> It was narrated that Abdullah Ibn Umar said:"The Messenger of Allah used to order dogs to be killed and I went throughout Al-Madina and we did not spare any dog but we killed it, to such an extent that we would even kill the dog of a woman belonging to the desert people"

I understand that dogs are Najis but does this give me the right to massacre all dogs?

Answer (score 2):

This was the command during the early period of migration, as there were many stray dogs and they caused nuisance and harm to the people, as anyone who has had to deal with them knows.

Later it was abrogated. There are different madhabs on the extent of abrogation, however according to the most it is not enjoined to kill a dog that does not cause harm.

> أمرنا رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم بقتل الكلاب حتى إن المرأة تقدم من البادية بكلبها فنقتله ثم نهى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم عن قتلها
>
> The Messenger of Allah ﷺ ordered us to kill dogs, and even if a woman came from the desert with a dog, we would kill it. Then the Prophet ﷺ forbade killing them.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/22/55-76)</sup>

Comment: Which madhab differs from the majority?

Comment: @Affan A group of the Malikis consider it permissible to kill a dog unless it be used for hunting or farming as in the [hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1571). Refer to [مواهب الجليل](https://ia800300.us.archive.org/8/items/FP137771/04_137774.pdf#page=31):

Answer (score 1):

In another hadith prophet said a person who collected water from well using a shoe in his mouth for a thirsty dog entered paradise.

> A man felt very thirsty while he was on the way; he came across a well. He went down the well, quenched his thirst and came out. Meanwhile he saw a dog panting and licking mud because of excessive thirst. He said to himself, "This dog is suffering from thirst as I did." So, he went down the well again and filled his shoe with water and watered it. Allah was pleased with him for that deed and forgave him."

> The people with the Messenger of Allah (pbuh) said,

> "O Messenger of Allah! Is there a reward for us in serving the animals?" The Prophet (pbuh) said,

> "Yes, there is a reward for serving any animate (living being)." [Bukhari, Shirb 9, Wudu 33, Mazalim 23, Adab 27; Muslim, Salam 153, (2244); Muwatta, Sifatun Nabi 23, (2, 929-930); Abu Dawud, Jihad 47, (2550)]

The hadith you stated and above hadith are contradicting compassion for animals.

There might be some harm averted by killing dogs of medinah only. Hence the command. He didn't order a person from iraq kills all dogs of Baghdad

Comment: Jazakallah Khair for the answer, btw i think it was actually a Prostitute of Bani Israel, not a man, which goes to show how merciful Allah (SWT) is :)

Comment: These dogs were not cute puppies offcourse but who chased humans in dark or alone. These wild dogs eat from garbage and if bite any human then can cause disease like rabbies. Anything which is harmful for humans are allowed to kill like snakes or scorpians.

Comment: The argument (at least superficially) is reasonable: since if being kind to it and saving its life is virtuous then mistreating it should be sinful. However note that even if killing it is enjoined then it is enjoined to kill in a good and swift manner ([hadith](https://sunnah.com/muslim/34/84)), torturing and making it die of thirst etc. is not permitted.